Will marginal effects for a logit link also be between 0-1?
I have a question on marginal effects.
I have some data in R (response is between 0 and 100, t is a time variable, predictors are continuous and greater than 0):
library(mgcv)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(marginaleffects)

set.seed(123)

n <- 500
t <- seq(0, 365, length.out = n) 
x1 <- rnorm(n, mean = 100, sd = 10)  
x2 <- rpois(n, lambda = 2)  

true_mean <- function(t, x1, x2) {
    base <- 0.4  
    x1_effect <- 0.003 * x1 * exp(-t/200) 
    x2_effect <- 0.05 * x2 * (1 - exp(-t/200))  
    time_effect <- 0.1 * sin(2 * pi * t/365) 
    return(base + x1_effect + x2_effect + time_effect)
}

y_mean <- true_mean(t, x1, x2)
y <- 100 * plogis(qlogis(y_mean) + rnorm(n, 0, 0.3)) 

sim_data <- data.frame(
    y = y,
    t = t,
    x1 = x1,
    x2 = x2
)

I fit a GAM regression to this:
$$ g(\mathbb{E}[Y_i]) = \beta_0 + f_1(t_i, x1_i) + f_2(t_i, x2_i) $$

$g(\cdot)$ is the logit link function $g(p) = \log(\frac{p}{1-p})$
$Y_i$ is a Beta distribution :  $Y_i \sim \text{Beta}(\alpha, \beta) $
$\beta_0$ is the intercept
$f_1$ and $f_2$ are smooth functions for the interaction effects between:($t$ and $x_1$)
and ($t$ and $x_2$)

Here is the R code - I chose the link function and family accordingly to respect the natural ranges of the response:
epsilon <- 0.001  
sim_data$y_scaled <- (sim_data$y * (1 - 2 * epsilon) + epsilon) / 100

gam_model <- gam(
    y_scaled ~ te(t, x1) + te(t, x2),
    data = sim_data,
    family = betar(link = "logit"),
    method = "REML"
)

Using this link (https://marginaleffects.com/bonus/gam.html), I wrote R code to find the marginal effects of each predictor on the response (over time) -  this involved creating a grid of points and calculating the marginal effects over the grid. What I am doing here: at a given time point, for each unit change in x (e.g. x1 or x2) - what is the estimated unit change in y:
get_marginal_effects <- function(model, variable, data, time_points) {
    effects_list <- list()
    
    for(curr_time in time_points) {
        newdata <- data.frame(
            t = curr_time,
            x1 = mean(data$x1),
            x2 = mean(data$x2)
        )
        
        # get slopes and scale to original units (0-100 scale) and  multiply by 100 here because our model was fit on 0-1 scale
        mfx <- slopes(model, 
                      variables = variable,
                      newdata = newdata)
        
        effects_list[[as.character(curr_time)]] <- data.frame(
            time = curr_time,
            effect = mfx$estimate * 100,      # convert to absolute units (0-100 scale)
            conf_low = mfx$conf.low * 100,    # scale confidence intervals
            conf_high = mfx$conf.high * 100
        )
    }
    
    return(do.call(rbind, effects_list))
}

time_points <- seq(0, 365, length.out = 50)

x1_effects <- get_marginal_effects(gam_model, "x1", sim_data, time_points)
x2_effects <- get_marginal_effects(gam_model, "x2", sim_data, time_points)

plot_effects <- function(effects_data, title, color) {
    ggplot(effects_data, aes(x = time)) +
        geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = conf_low, ymax = conf_high),
                    fill = color, alpha = 0.2) +
        geom_line(aes(y = effect),
                  color = color, size = 1) +
        geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed",
                   color = "gray50") +
        theme_minimal() +
        labs(
            title = title,
            x = "Days",
            y = "Change in Response (Absolute Units)" 
        ) +
        theme(
            plot.title = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
            panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            plot.margin = unit(c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5), "cm")
        )
}

p1 <- plot_effects(x1_effects, "Marginal Effect of X1 Over Time", "#4E79A7")
p2 <- plot_effects(x2_effects, "Marginal Effect of X2 Over Time", "#E15759")


As a sanity check, I want to see the following point: If I play around with the marginal effects, e.g. I am interested in knowing the estimated change in the response for a 50 unit change in x1 - will the estimated marginal effect remain between the (-100,100) range? I would want this as the response in real life can not exceed 100.
I tried to re-write the earlier marginal effects function for this problem:
get_large_effects_with_ci <- function(model, variable, data, time_points, delta = 50) {
    effects_list <- list()
    
    for(curr_time in time_points) {
        base_data <- data.frame(
            t = curr_time,
            x1 = mean(data$x1),
            x2 = mean(data$x2)
        )
        
        comp_data <- base_data
        comp_data[[variable]] <- base_data[[variable]] + delta
        
        base_pred <- predict(model, newdata = base_data, 
                           type = "link", se.fit = TRUE)
        comp_pred <- predict(model, newdata = comp_data, 
                           type = "link", se.fit = TRUE)
        
        base_response <- plogis(base_pred$fit) * 100
        comp_response <- plogis(comp_pred$fit) * 100
        
        effect <- comp_response - base_response
        

        se_diff <- sqrt(base_pred$se.fit^2 + comp_pred$se.fit^2)
        
        ci_lower_link <- (comp_pred$fit - base_pred$fit) - 1.96 * se_diff
        ci_upper_link <- (comp_pred$fit - base_pred$fit) + 1.96 * se_diff
        
   
        ci_lower_resp <- (plogis(base_pred$fit + ci_lower_link) - 
                         plogis(base_pred$fit)) * 100
        ci_upper_resp <- (plogis(base_pred$fit + ci_upper_link) - 
                         plogis(base_pred$fit)) * 100
        
        effects_list[[as.character(curr_time)]] <- data.frame(
            time = curr_time,
            effect = effect,
            conf_low = ci_lower_resp,
            conf_high = ci_upper_resp
        )
    }
    
    return(do.call(rbind, effects_list))
}

time_points <- seq(0, 365, length.out = 50)
x1_large_effects <- get_large_effects_with_ci(gam_model, "x1", sim_data, time_points, delta = 50)
x2_large_effects <- get_large_effects_with_ci(gam_model, "x2", sim_data, time_points, delta = 50)

plot_large_effects <- function(effects_data, title, color) {
    ggplot(effects_data, aes(x = time)) +
        geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = conf_low, ymax = conf_high),
                    fill = color, alpha = 0.2) +
        geom_line(aes(y = effect),
                  color = color, size = 1) +
        geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed",
                   color = "gray50") +
        theme_minimal() +
        labs(
            title = title,
            x = "Days",
            y = "Change in Response for Δx = 50 (Absolute Units)" 
        ) +
        theme(
            plot.title = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
            panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            plot.margin = unit(c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5), "cm")
        )
}

p1_large <- plot_large_effects(x1_large_effects, 
                              "Effect of 50-Unit Change in X1 Over Time", 
                              "#4E79A7")
p2_large <- plot_large_effects(x2_large_effects, 
                              "Effect of 50-Unit Change in X2 Over Time", 
                              "#E15759")


It seems like the logical ranges are respected. Is my analysis correct - do marginal effects respect the original ranges of the link function and family? Does my R code look correct?

If I understand, you have the regression $\hat y^{(i)}= f(x_1^{(i)},x_2^{(i)})$ and you're estimating an average effect $\frac{1}{n}\sum_i(\hat y^{(i)} - \tilde y^{(i)})$ for $\tilde y^{(i)}=f(x_1^{(i)} + 50, x_2)$ for each of the $i$ observations. In all cases, $f$ is bounded between 0 and 100, because that's how the (scaled) logistic function works, so the largest possible value is 100 = 100 - 0 and the smallest possible value is -100 = 0 - 100. Does this answer your question?

I think this answers my question! :)

I just hope I wrote the R code correctly ...

I have also worked out some of the math behind this, I can post it here if necessary

As I understand your question, you have the regression $\hat y^{(i)}= h(x_1^{(i)},x_2^{(i)})= 100 g^{-1}\left( \beta_0 + f_1(t^{(i)}, x_1^{(i)}) + f_2(t^{(i)}, x_2^{(i)})\right)$ and you're estimating an average effect $\frac{1}{n}\sum_i(\hat y^{(i)} - \tilde y^{(i)})$ for $\tilde y^{(i)}=h(x_1^{(i)} + 50, x_2^{(i)})$ for each of the $i$ observations. In all cases, $h$ is bounded between 0 and 100, because the sigmoid function $g^{-1}$ is bounded in [0,1] and multiplying by 100 just increases the upper bound, resulting in the range [0,100].
So the largest possible value is $100 = 100 - 0$ and the smallest possible value is $-100 = 0 - 100$.

Sycorax : can you please take a look at my R code? Does it looks reasonable to you?

While the probabilities in a logistic regression are neatly bounded between 0 and 1, the marginal effects themselves are not so well-behaved. These effects represent the change in the probability of the outcome for a one-unit change in the predictor variable, holding everything else constant. They can be positive or negative and can even exceed 1 or drop below -1. This is because the logistic function is non-linear, and the steepness of the curve varies depending on where you are on it. So, no, marginal effects are not confined to the 0-1 range.

I think this answer misunderstands the question. The author is asking about the range of possible values for $\mathbb{E}(\hat y^{(i)} - \tilde y^{(i)})$, not the values of the coefficients.
